# Examples of hyperbolic manifolds of dimension $\geq$ 3 with disjoint totally geodesic hypersurfaces

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, arithmetic-groups

I am hoping to find examples of compact hyperbolic manifolds with at least 2 disjoint totally geodesic hypersurfaces. Ideally, I would like examples in dimension at least 4, though 3-dimensional manifolds would be good too. At least one of these hypersurfaces should be separating (the other(s) need not be).

I know that [arithmetic techniques](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312548/hyperbolic-manifolds-containing-totally-geodesic-hypersurfaces-which-themselves) can be used to construct hyperbolic manifolds containing a totally geodesic hypersurface which is separating (and can be adapted to get nested totally geodesic submanifolds). However, I am not experienced enough with hyperbolic geometry/geometric group theory/number theory to know if these techniques can be adapted to create arithmetic hyperbolic manifolds which contain disjoint totally geodesic hypersurfaces.

Any references would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not have a self-contained reference, but the key is

*Long, D. D.; Reid, A. W.*, [**Constructing hyperbolic manifolds which bound geometrically**](https://doi.org/10.4310/MRL.2001.v8.n4.a5), Math. Res. Lett. 8, No. 4, 443-455 (2001). [ZBL0992.57023](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0992.57023).

where they construct, for every $n\ge 2$ a closed hyperbolic $n$-manifold $N$ and a compact separating connected totally geodesic hypersurface $M\subset N$. By adapting their proof, one obtains examples of manifolds $N$ containing not only manifolds $M$ as above but arbitrariliy large (finite) number of non-separating compact totally-geodesic hypersurfaces disjoint from $M$. But to prove this, one has to understand the details of the proof of their main theorem.  In dimension 3 one can give a different proof using Thurston's hyperbolization theorem.

Comment: Once you have a manifold $M$ with a (connected) geodesic boundary $W=\partial M$, the fundamental group of $W$ is separable *, and hence it lifts to a (non-trivial) finite-sheeted cover $M’$ of $M$. Double $M’$ along $\partial M’-W$, then cap off the two copies of $W$ with two copies of $M$. This should give a desired manifold.  * separability by Long https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=898729

Comment: Thank you very much both of you! I had actually read the Long and Reid paper a couple years ago but I did not understand their techniques well enough to adapt them.